# Raspberry pi autostart of LXDE does not work

Tags: lxde, kiosk

I upgraded a raspberry Pi installation with a Pi 2. But since I upgraded all packages, the autostart does not work anymore:

neither this seems to be working:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

nor this:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

the content of the autostart file is:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
#@xscreensaver -no-splash
# Auto run the browser
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@/usr/bin/epiphany-browser -a --profile ~/.config http://google.de
@sleep 5s # give it time to start
@echo key F11 | xte # simulate pressing the full screen key
```

How can I configure that the `autostart` is executed?

Comment: Stupid question/sanity check: Have you confirmed that the autostart file isn't run by replacing your commands with something *really* basic? For example, remove everything below '#Auto run the browser' and test '@midori'.

Comment: Yes I did that. It is simply not exectued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with a cron task.

First I installed the packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule
```

The I edited the crontab via:

```
crontab -e
```

I added a task after each reboot where I put the browser startup:

```
@reboot /home/pi/startupscript &
```

Answer (score 22):

There's a fairly plausible sounding explanation for your problem in [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=131760) on the [raspberrypi.org forums.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/)

> `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`
>
> That is the global autostart file, and works for all users... unless
>   they have a user autostart. If the user has an autostart file the
>   global one is ignored and the personal autostart is used. User
>   settings are applied last and take precedence over global settings.
>   Jessie creates a user's autostart file during the install, so changing
>   settings in the global file no longer have any effect.
>
> `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`
>
> That is the "old" location, the new location uses "/LXDE-pi/". The
>   "/LXDE/" directory may exist, but it will be ignored.

The correct location for adding autostart items should be `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`. It's recommended that you *don't* use sudo to edit it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but I changed the ownership to pi:pi, but that does not work either.

Comment: Sorry, could you confirm what you changed the ownership of? That shouldn't be necessary here.

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 414 Mar 18 06:55 /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

Comment: That isn't going to help here - the user level settings will still take precedence over those settings. You need to copy/paste your commands over to ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart .

Comment: After a `cp /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` there is no change in behaviour

Comment: I'm afraid that lands me pretty much out of suggestions. There's a walkthrough [here](http://blog.startingelectronics.com/auto-start-a-desktop-application-on-the-rapberry-pi/) that may include something I've missed, but as far as I can tell this is how autostart configurations are handled.

Comment: Why we should not use sudo to edit it?

Answer (score 12):

Experienced the same issue. Here are my findings:

Check if the `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` file exists. If it exists, it will be used instead of `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`.

View logs (after reboot) in `/home/pi/.xsession-errors`:

```
$ cat .xsession-errors
Xsession: X session started for pi at Sat 30 Jul 23:14:04 UTC 2016
localuser:pi being added to access control list
** Message: main.vala:99: Session is LXDE-pi
** Message: main.vala:100: DE is LXDE
** Message: main.vala:131: log directory: /home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi
** Message: main.vala:132: log path: /home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi/run.log
```

This suggest looking at `/home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi/run.log`:

```
$ tail -n30 /home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi/run.log
...

** (epiphany-browser:874): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
--profile must be an existing directory when --application-mode is requested
** Message: app.vala:130: /usr/bin/epiphany-browser exit with this type of exit: 256

...
```

So I tested the command manually in the terminal (in the GUI). I got some errors:

```
$ /usr/bin/epiphany-browser -a --profile ~/.config https~://google.de

** (epiphany-browser:1218): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
** Message: Remote error from secret service: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files

** (epiphany-browser:1218): WARNING **: Error caching form data: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files
```

But the browser started anyway...

Played with the `/usr/bin/epiphany-browser` command and reduced it to `/usr/bin/epiphany-browser --profile ~/.config https://google.de`.

Then changed the `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` lines to:

```
@/usr/bin/epiphany-browser --profile ~/.config https://google.de
```

And it worked - the browser started.

Tested on:

- Raspberry Pi 3
- Debian Jessie

  ```
  $ lsb_release -a
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Raspbian
  Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
  Release:    8.0
  Codename:   jessie
  ```

Comment: "Check if the /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart file exists. If it exists, it will be used" - that saved my day!

Answer (score 4):

Yesterday I downloaded NOOBS and created a new micro SD installer. After Raspian installation everything looked OK at first until I looked at autostart. I found that the folder /home/pi/.config/lxsession did not exist so I created it and the folder /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi. I then created the file autostart as an empty file and added my autostart command. After reboot I had a black screen. I have other working Pis and I checked their autostart files. They have these lines

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@point-rpi
```

Adding these lines in the new installation fixed the problem.

I am adding this answer for the benefit of someone else like me who is looking for a solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Three things that tripped me up:

- the user's autostart *overrides* the global one; if you want to start everything as usual *plus* your custom commands, copy the default and *add* your commands to the end:

  cp /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart $HOME/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/
  editor $HOME/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
- in `$HOME/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/desktop.conf`, there's this part - if `disable_autostart=yes`, it won't run (obvious in retrospect, yes):

  [Session]
  disable_autostart=no
- autostart is not a shell script. If you need anything beyond simply launching programs, better make a shell script and call that *from* the autostart (E.g. `foo && bar` won't work here)

Answer (score 0):

write on these path the autostart - `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/`

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@/usr/bin/chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --incognito "USE URL¨S HERE, IF YOU WANT TO USE MORE THAN ONE USE A SPACE FOR EACH URL"
@/usr/bin/xdotool x y
```

Also you can change the `--start-fullscreen` for kiosk, but kiosk needs to kill the process of your app.

Command: `pkill chromium`

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error:

```
[1216:1216:0128/120813.940515:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(582)] Failed to put Xlib into threaded mode.

(chromium-browser:1216): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I Managed to overcome it using this [tutorial](https://www.ketzler.de/2017/12/installing-chromium-on-raspberry-pi-without-desktop/).

I Installed window-manager

```
$ sudo apt-get install matchbox-window-manager
```

Then I included this in `.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` BEFORE starting Chromium.

```
@matchbox-window-Manager -use_cursor no&
```

Then a command of starting chromium-browser with my options.