# autostart Chromium using Pixel

Tags: chromium, pixel, kiosk

I'm about done with this, for two days i have tried to simply autostart Chromium on a pi for a project at work but nothing happens when I reboot.

**Using the path** - 
~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

**With the command** -
#various xset stuff here for kiosk mode

@chromium-browser --incognito --kiosk www.google.com #just an example site btw

Chromium boots fine with the command chromium-browser. Everwhere Ive looked im doing it right and it works for everyone else. If it matters I installed Raspbian Lite and install pixel over the top (with no applications) and then installed Chromium to save resources.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: I wouldn't use ~.  Replace that with the full path.

Answer (score 1):

To add to or edit your user's autostart:

```
nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Ref.: [Raspberry pi autostart of LXDE does not work](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42633/raspberry-pi-autostart-of-lxde-does-not-work)