# How to run a command on login?

Tags: pi-3

I use the command `wmctrl -n4` manually to create 4 desktops each time my Raspberry Pi reboots. My OS version info are as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l

$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.47-v7+ #1033 SMP Mon Sep 4 21:48:16 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I tried to put this command `/usr/bin/wmctrl -n4` to `/etc/rc.local`, or `~pi/.bashrc`, neither ever worked. So is there a way to avoid the manual work on each reboot? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `wmctrl` needs to talk to the X server.  So you don't want it to run at startup (at least not when rc.local runs), you want it to run when the X server launches.  In addition, you need it to know what DISPLAY it should be talking to.

[Raspberry pi autostart of LXDE does not work](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42633/raspberry-pi-autostart-of-lxde-does-not-work) has background information about starting programs when the X server does.  It appears though that when the autostart script fires, the desktops *still* aren't ready for `wmctrl` to control.  So the best thing is to write a small script that introduces a short delay.  I used 10 seconds and it was fine.  You could probably get away with less most of the time, but I wouldn't think you'd need much less.

Create the script and make it executable.  I placed the script in the user's "bin" directory

```
mkdir ~/bin
printf '#!/bin/bash\nsleep 10\nwmctrl -n4\n' > ~/bin/wmscript
chmod a+x ~/bin/wmscript
```

Tell the X session to run the script.  Add the path to the script with an `@` symbol at the beginning of the line.

```
printf "@bin/wmscript" >> ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Now the next time you start an X session (logout or reboot), it should set your desktops a few seconds after login.

Answer (score 1):

From the link below:

2. Put a script containing the command in your /etc directory. Create a script such as "startup.sh" using your favorite text editor. Save the file in your /etc/init.d/ directory. Change the permissions of the script (to make it executable) by typing "chmod +x /etc/init.d/mystartup.sh".

Here is the original link: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/run-command-startup-linux-27796.html

Wrap your command into a basic bash/shell script and then follow the instructions above. If you need further assistance, just comment and I can walk you through it.