# Problem running a Python3 script at startup with lxsessions

Tags: boot, python-3, lxde, lxsession

I have Raspbian Buster on a RPi4 and I was launching a Python3 based Kivy 2.0 app at startup. Since it is a GUI app that needs networking and bluetooth. The only way to make it work was an executable script with `sudo chmod +x myapp.py` and add the line `@python3 ~/myapp.py` to  `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`.

Later on I installed Teamviewer and at the startup the app simply does not start any more. I have checked all the LXDE-pi autostarts, configs, desktops, lxpanels, lxsessions, xdges without finding a flaw. The only change I found was teeamviewer added a  service in `etc/systemd/system`. Uninstalling teamviewer did not help.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE n.1**

The file `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` does not exist so it is not used instead of /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart.

In `$HOME/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/desktop.conf` the part `disable_autostart=no`, so it should be fine.

My app launched only using `lxsessions/autostart`. Other attempts such with rc.local,[autostart desktop files](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/run-script-at-boot-raspberry-pi), [systemd](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md), [crontab](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up),init.d and bashrc did not have a positive outcome and I can not consider them as solutions.

**UPDATE n.2**

Teamviewer is not guilty. I tested with a simple script and `lxsessions` does run after boot.

The script myapp.py works fine when launched any time except after reboot. After checking `/home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi/run.log` it seems to be a serial tty port problem. This is the post where I found out about `run.log` [raspberry-pi-autostart-of-lxde-does-not-work](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42633/raspberry-pi-autostart-of-lxde-does-not-work#44278).

Comment: Are there any actual error messages associated with "failed miserably" and "went bananas"? In general, you should make your question more focused. If you managed to start your script though `lxsession` autostart, and this is now broken, ask how to fix that, don't mention `crontab` and friends. If you want to switch to `crontab` or `systemd`, ask specifically about that.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I mentioned crontab and friends to avoid proposing them as alternatives as they do not work. Unfortunately there are no errors visible that I could post, the app simply does not start. Thank you for the suggiestion about narrowing the question.

Comment: Another point: does  `lxsession` still run, or did it get removed / disabled when you installed Teamviewer? And BTW, `systemd` or a `.desktop` may be a good alternative, despite the fact you couldn't set it up before.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev,  `lxsessions` is still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When launched my script initializes the serial ports ttyACM*. After failing with `lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` I went to see the lxsession autostart log `.cache/lxsesion/LXDE-pi/rpi.log`. I found out my script was not able to open the serial port only at startup, right after boot. It was not a matter of permissions or timing. After playing with `crontab`, `bash` and `lxsession`, I removed `sudo apt-get purge modemmanager` as suggested in the [Arduino forum](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/47429/failed-to-open-dev-ttyacm0-port-busy) and now my script works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try adding a simple app to your autostart file, e.g. `leafpad`, just to make sure it is still in use. If Leafpad won't run, you'll have to concentrate on your desktop environment / session configuration. Perhaps checking log files in `/home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi` will shed some light on the situation.

Otherwise, the problem is in your script. I would replace `~/myapp.py` with an absolute path to be sure, and then add some code to it which logs the progress to a file.

Comment: I tested with a simple script and `lxsessions` does run after boot. It seems to be a problem with opening a serial tty port right after boot.

Answer (score 0):

Although this topic is not new, the autostart problem resurfaced newly again. The fact that Conky was not auto-starting anymore,  made me aware of this new issue.
After some unsuccessful efforts by using the latest hints that I found on the web, I tried:

```
    /home/myusername/.config/autostart-scripts
```

by adding a symlink to a shell-script (see image below) .
The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
stat='df -h'              # get status of mounted drives
$stat > ~/startstatus     # and (over)write to file startstatus
stat2="sudo systemctl status home_autom"  # get the status of service 
$stat2 >> ~/startstatus   # and append to above file

sleep 45
conky -obdq   # start conky
```

Now conky pops up again at boottime. By checking the modification date of the file startstatus can be verified whether the script worked or failed.

My system:
Raspberry 3 B+ Linux raspi10 5.10.52-v7+ #1441 SMP Tue Aug 3 18:10:09 BST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
Raspbian lite + KDE

[image: screenshot midnight commander]